# Why the CSS inherit property overrides my style?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, kendo-grid, css-specificity

In the following example I have a Bootstrap button style which is hijacked by the `color: inherit` entry set by `.k-grid` of Kendo-UI:

```css
.k-grid a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="k-grid">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/299912/

You can observe that the `inherit` property of `.k-grid a` bypasses any other classes passed to the `a` tag. Eventually the Bootstrap Button is displayed with the wrong color inside a Kendo-grid table.

What is the correct way to fix this? I am not sure that adding a `!important` to the SASS of Bootstrap is the best solution.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can experiment and debug.

Comment: Because CSS means CascadeStyleSheet. And `.k-grid a` has bigger "value" than `.btn-sm`. More selectors = more value

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: In CSS there is a "value" that's dependent on where this style is "external file/inline/embedded(<style> in head)" and on selector which is tag/class/id

Comment: @csmckelvey I have edited my question with a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @ksav, I have read your link and understood that `.hijack tag` will bypass all classes passed to `tag` if it has an `inherit` close. But this is not clear how I can fix my issue.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `.hijack tag`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at your fiddle, I can see in the inspector that Bootstrap's reset applies the following: `a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {color: inherit;}`

On top of this, the anchor in your fiddle doesn't have an href so the above CSS applies.

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="k-grid">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Button</a>

  <a class="btn btn-secondary">Button</a>
</div>
```

So trying to style your button (without a href) with:
`.btn-secondary {color: white;}` will not work due to [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

---

If you are still confused about [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), find yourself a specificity calculator like [this one](https://specificity.keegan.st/) and paste both selectors in.

You will find that `.btn-secondary` *is not specific enough* to override this rule coming from Bootstrap's reset that applies styles for your button.

---

Given that kendo-ui is also affecting your button styles with: `.k-grid a {color: inherit;}`, the best way to solve your issue is by targeting the button with (you guessed it) a selector of higher specificity.

```css
.k-grid a {
  color: inherit;
}

.btn.btn-secondary {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="k-grid">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Button</a>

  <a class="btn btn-secondary">Button</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to understand the css specificity 
For example: http://cssspecificity.com

In your case .one-class is less specific than .on-class and an element

Comment: @Laurent Thanks your your answer. I have read your link and edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The inherit CSS keyword causes the element for which it is specified to take the computed value of the property from its parent element. It can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all.

For inherited properties, this reinforces the default behavior, and is only needed to override another rule.

This would help you :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Cascade_and_inheritance

If you want to dig in more :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit ,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/computed_value